# Question on a paper of Montesano

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Does anyone know what are the results in the paper

"D. Montesano, Rendiconti della Reale Accademia di Napoli, Ser. 3, Vol. 13 (1907), Su novi tipi di superficie razionali di 5 ordine"? I have one pdf file but it is in Italian so I don't understand what it says, and the format makes it impossible to cut and paste into Google translate.

More specially, whether in that paper Montesano classified all rational surfaces of degree 5?

Thank you.

Edit:

@quid: Thanks for the suggestion. I looked at Zentralblatt Review. I don't know German either so used Google translate. The Review did not mention anything about rational quintic surfaces, if I read the translation correctly.

@Valerio: You can read the paper online at the link http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=chi.099038480;view=1up;seq=74

Comment: Did you check the Zentralblatt MATH/JFM review? (It is in German but also would be copy-able.) [Since you have precise bib-data subscription is a non-issue as the first results of a search are always given.]

Comment: try to send me the pdf by email. I am not expert in the topic, but I think I can do at least the word-by-word translation :)

Comment: the online link only works if you're in the US (silly copyright restrictions...)

Comment: @Carlo: Thank your for the information, I didn't know that. Then I will try to see if there is another way to do.